# "git branch --merged <sha>" via Rugged libgit2 bindings?

Tags: ruby, libgit2, rugged

Is there any way to get the same information as the native git command

```
git branch --merged <sha>
```

via the [Rugged](https://github.com/libgit2/rugged) libgit2 bindings for Ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What that git commit is doing is looking at each branch and checking whether the merge-base between the branch and the commit you've given (or HEAD if none) corresponds to the one of the branch.

If they match, it's merged; if they don't, it's not. You can do this loop in ruby fairly easily

```
repo.branches.each(:local) # look only at local branches
.map { |b|
  tgt = b.resolve.target # look at what the branch is pointing to
  # and check if the target commit is included in the history of HEAD
  merged = repo.merge_base(repo.head.target, tgt) == tgt.oid
  [b.name, merged]
} # this will give a list with the name and whether the branch is merged
.keep_if { |name, merged| merged } # keep only the ones which are merged
.map(&:first) # get the name
```

You could have an `merged_list << b.name if merged` in the first block and make it hang off of the `each`, but I like composing streams of data.

You can also change whether to use `:local`, `:remote` or both for the branches depending on your need. And you can also change `repo.head.target` to whatever id you want to compare against.